# Rspec/Capybara Rails Where to put require 'capybara/rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In a Rails app does the `require 'capybara/rails'` go in spec/rails_helper.rb? Also how about the `require 'capybara/rspec'`? Does it go in spec/rspec_helper.rb? and not spec/rails_helper.rb ... what is the purpose of both of those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the top of your **rails_helper.rb** file. Here are the setup instructions from their [docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#setup). Below is an example of the top of my `rails_helper` and the location of where I placed the `require 'capybara/rspec'`.

The purpose of the file is to load each test you run with a specific configuration. Thus you add the line `require 'rails_helper'` to the top of each test file like so:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyModel, :type => :model do
  # add your tests here
end
```

I found this [resource](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#default-helper-files) helpful regarding the new use of two of these files. The file `rails_helper.rb` is new to RSpec 3x, whereas in RSpec 2x, the default helper file was `spec_helper.rb`.

Here is an example of the first few lines in one of my `rails_helper.rb` files. It should tell you where to place the code `require 'capybara/rspec'`

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)  
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

As an example of certain configuration for each test run, when I test image uploads, I want to delete the uploaded file after each test, so I configured my `rails_helper.rb` to do that.

```
config.after(:each) do
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
    FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads"])
  end 
end
```

For some apps, I also like to use [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers), and to use this feature, you have to make sure you require it for your tests, thus you add `require 'shoulda/matchers` to your `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: Thanks. What should go in rspec_helper.rb?

Comment: What [Relish says](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#default-helper-files) is `Move any non-Rails RSpec configurations and customizations from your
rails_helper.rb to spec_helper.rb.`. With my current configuration, I didn't need `spec_helper.rb` so I removed it and removed it from the top of my `rails_helper.rb` file where it said `require spec_helper`.